# Getting Python error -->PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to read a csv file from local path using python & then I process the records of csv file into json structure , finally printing them on console. I have written the code within try & except block.I'm expecting that if any exception happens in the try block while reading the data from csv file, the except block should print that exception has occured & it should move the csv file from current location to folder called errored. But while testing via simulating the errored scenario ,it is unable to move the csv in errored folder.Instead it throws error:- "PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".Below is the code:-

```
try:
   global df
   df = pd.read_csv('CBD_BU_FULL.csv', encoding='UTF-8', dtype=str)
   df = df.assign(FILE_TYPE ='BU')
   data = df.to_json(orient = "records", lines=False).split('\n')
   print(data)

except:
   print("An exception occurred")    
   os.rename('CBD_BU_FULL.csv', '/Errored/CBD_BU_FULL.csv')
```

Comment: is the csv file open with some other editor, while you run the python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that `pd.read_csv` isn't properly closing the file since it is crashing mid read, I would try opening the file yourself so that in the except your own program is definitely closing the file and this may fix your issue.

```
import traceback
import pandas as pd
try:
   with open('CBD_BU_FULL.csv', "r") as f:
       df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='UTF-8', dtype=str)
   df = df.assign(FILE_TYPE ='BU')
   data = df.to_json(orient = "records", lines=False).split('\n')
   print(data)

except:
   traceback.print_exc(1)
   os.rename('CBD_BU_FULL.csv', '/Errored/CBD_BU_FULL.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `os.rename` if the file is in use. You could use [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) instead.

Comment: I have also tried with this: shutil.move('CBD_BU_FULL.csv', '/Errored/CBD_BU_FULL.csv') & i'm getting the exact same error

Comment: Perhaps `shutil.move` csnnot be used when the file is in use. Did you try `shutil.copy`?

Comment: yeah shutil.copy is working...so this means I need to delete the file after copy of file happens. But I guess for deleting also the file must get closed first. How can I close the file once the reading through panda has happened. @np8

Comment: If the file is reserved by another process you cannot move or remove it. This kind of situation typically happens if the file is open in another program (e.g. Excel). If you cannot find out what process is using your file, just relogin/reboot. On windows, you can check with resmon what process is using the file (search the handles).